# How to activate iPhone with forgotten details

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-id

I brought my uncles old iPhone 4S and I've reset it, but now it's asking for his Apple ID and password and he can't remember it and he has lost his passcode. How can I activate the phone without the passcode?

Answer (score 0):

Well you would need to get the Apple ID first, then reset it with your Apple ID.

To recover your ID password: [iForgot](https://iforgot.apple.com/)